# How to find a specific email address/user in wordpress and woocommerce?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, command-line-interface, bitnami

I need to find a specific email address. I use something similar to the below but it returns empty. I'm pretty sure it does exist somewhere in the database as I still receive emails from that particular address. I think it could be some hard-coded theme setting from the past.

```
sudo mysql -u bn_wordpress -p -e "USE bitnami_wordpress; SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE '%some-email@example.com';"
```

Comment: With only leading wildcard (`%`) in `WHERE option_name LIKE '%some-email@example.com'`? What if the e-mail is something like `some-email@example.com.my` or `some-email@example.co.uk` ? OR what if its not ending with `.com`?

Comment: Oh wait, my bad.. you said it's a specific e-mail address.

Comment: yes. specific. Thank @FanoFN

Comment: Well, with _specific email address_ in mind, I don't think there's anything wrong with your query. Perhaps, you can try different variation of `LIKE` wildcards. Maybe `LIKE '%some-email@domain%'` or just `LIKE '%some-email%'`. If you still can't find it, then maybe it's not there.